# How to write equations in Latex by having "forall" on the right side of the equations

Tags: latex

I am trying to write a equation in Latex according to a format shown below, where it nicely has "forall n \in N_{s}, s in S" on the right side of the equation. However, I could not. I would like to know that is it possible to do this in Latex ?

[image]

Thank you.
Note that this equation is taken from the following reference.
H. Alameddine, M. H. K. Tushar and C. Assi, "Scheduling of Low Latency Services in Softwarized Networks," in IEEE Transactions on Cloud Computing.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that includes everything you were able to do? Then we can just add the rest and don't have to start from zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just write

```
\[
\sum_{f\in F}\sum_{\delta \in \Delta} y_{ns}^{s \delta} = a_s \qquad \forall n\in N_s, \ \forall s\in S
\]
```

which gives a nice enough equation with your the quantifier statements horizontally on the right. If you insist in having them vertically aligned, you can put them in a matrix like this

```
\[
\sum_{f\in F}\sum_{\delta \in \Delta} y_{ns}^{s \delta} = a_s \qquad \begin{matrix}
&\forall n\in N_s, \\
&\forall s\in S
\end{matrix}
\]
```

But once you are down that path you might as well bother to nicely align the 'for all' quantifiers.

```
\[
\sum_{f\in F}\sum_{\delta \in \Delta} y_{ns}^{s \delta} = a_s \qquad \begin{matrix*}[l]
&\forall n\in N_s, \\
&\forall s\in S
\end{matrix*}
\]
```

do however make sure to use the `mathtools` package for the last option.

[image]